# blur event not firing on iOS Mobile Safari in Sencha Touch

Tags: ios, sencha-touch, mobile-safari, blur

I'm using iOS 5.0.1, and Sencha Touch 2-rc1. I have a search input field where the focus event is getting triggered, as well as the submit event when I press 'Search' on the on-screen keyboard. The blur event doesn't get triggered when I expect it to, which would be when the 'Done' key is pressed, or the viewable area is tapped.

Note that the blur event IS getting triggered on my laptop in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely to be related to **the event not "bubbling" up through the DOM**. Or perhaps the code you've used includes an event.preventDefault(), but that would have killed more than just blur. I've also had this issue with clicking *away* from items which appear via javascript.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html

Answer (score 6):

Not every element is focusable. At least `<div>` is not.

`onblur` is not firing because when a user taps on a div element, the focus doesn't go to the `<div>`.

Based on this post:

http://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex

`tabindex` on the correct `div` element can make a `div` focusable.